# Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, api, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am writing an endpoint that would create a record but before then, I want to be able to validate if one of those data exist before allowing the data to be saved. This is being done using the custom validator in express-validator. I am also using Sequelize as well.

My migration files looks like this:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('merchant_temp', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      firstname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      lastname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      ip_address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      created_at: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updated_at: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });

  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('merchant_temp');
  }
};
```

Model file (merchanttemp.js)

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model, Sequelize
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class MerchantTemp extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  MerchantTemp.init({
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    lastname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ip_address: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'merchant_temp',
  });
  return MerchantTemp;
};
```

validator.js

```
const { check, body, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const models = require('../app/models')
const MerchantTemp = db.rest.models.MerchantTemp

const signupValidation = () => {
    return [
        body('firstname')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Firstname field is required'),
        body('lastname')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Lastname field is required'),
        body('phone')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Phone Number field is required')
            .isNumeric().withMessage('Phone Number field can only contain Numbers')
            .isLength({min: 11, max: 13}).withMessage('Phone Number field can only contain minimum of 11 and max of 13 digits respectively'),
        body('email')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Email Address field is required')
            .isEmail().withMessage('Email field is not a valid format').normalizeEmail()
            .custom((value, { req }) => {
               /**
                ** THIS PART IS WHERE I AM VALIDATING IF IT EXIST
               **/
                MerchantTemp.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } })
                    .then((result) => {
                        console.log(result)
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }),
        body('password')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Password field is required')
            .isStrongPassword(
                {
                    minLength: 6, 
                    minLowercase: 1, 
                    minUppercase: 1, 
                    minSymbols: 1
                }).withMessage('Password is too weak. Field must contain min. of 6 characters, 1 lowercase and uppercase character and a symbol')
    ]
}

const validate = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        return next()
    }
    const extractedErrors = []
    errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push({ msg: err.msg }))

    res.status(200).json({
        statusCode: 400,
        errors: extractedErrors
    })
}

module.exports = {
    signupValidation,
    validate
}
```

**router file**

```
require('dotenv').config()

const router = require('express').Router()
const account = require('../controllers/account.controller')

const { signupValidation, validate } = require('../../helpers/validator')


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let p = "This serves as a repository of API calls for application"
    res.status(200).json({message:p, statusCode: 200})
})

//Endpoint to create new merchant
router.post('/account/create-merchant', signupValidation(), validate, async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ 
        statusCode: 201,
        message: req.body
    })
})

//Endpoint to login merchant
router.post('/account/login', (req, res) => {

})



module.exports = router
```

The validation on the /account/create-merchant route works well prior to when I included the findOne part in the validator.js. What exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you include `app/models/index.js`?

Comment: I don't understand where this should be placed. Can you explain a bit more

Comment: Ok I see you've edited your code. The only `findOne` call is made on `MerchantTemp.findOne` and `MerchantTemp = `db.rest.models.MerchantTemp` so you need to look into why is that null